# Why doesn't my for loop execute?

Tags: javascript

When i use document.write it works, but it doesn't work with getElementById.
The same for while.
`

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
    <script>
        var i = 0;
        for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
        //while (i<=10){
            document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = i + "<br>";
            //i++;
        }
    </script>
```

Output is just 10, but I want to list 0-10 line by line. How to fix?

Comment: You are overwriting the content on each iteration.

Comment: You need to append, not replace.

Comment: InnerHTML overwrites the div each iteration through the loop.

Comment: Your problem is in assuming that the `for` loop doesn't execute because you don't get the results you expect.  A `console.log` or using the debugger to step through would have shown the loop was working.  Not getting the expected OUTCOME of that loop is a different matter.

Answer (score 2):

Each time your loop ran, it overwrite innerHTML for the div.

This implementation starts with an empty string for **html**, then uses **+=** to concatenate the counter and **<br>** on each iteration.

```
    var i = 0;
    var html = '';
    for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
        html += i + '<br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Thank you for *not* suggesting `.innerHTML += "..."` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-writing or replacing the contents. You need to append, so you can use `+=` operator instead of `=`.

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
  var i = 0;
  for (i=0; i<=10; i++){
    document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML += i + "<br>";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting. Append instead.

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  var div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "<br/>" + i;
}
```

```html
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While other answers are true, I think it's a risky practice because your browser might try to execute the code before having loaded all html elements. (For example if your div is *after* the code..)

So I propose this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
<script>
    for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){
        document.write ( i + "<br />");
    }
</script>
</div>
```

N.B: However, keep in mind you cannot use "document.write" *after* the page finished loading.

You can also do that to be safe:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script>
    document.onload = function(){
        temp=""
        for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){
            temp += i + "<br />";
        }
        document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = temp;
    }
</script>
```